# Depreciation warnings in Tensorflow Keras official tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, keras

The example code

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add a softmax layer with 10 output units:
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

in the official [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) results in a warning in the output as seen in that page itself.

```
calling VarianceScaling.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
```

What is the reason of the warning? How should the code be changed to avoid such warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the club :)  I mean tensorflow is notorious for not being backward compatible and worse yet there are warnings like this now for a long time.

See here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25996

So your best bet is just ignore those warnings and, if you wish to be proactive, then contribute with a fix. Otherwise, make sure they do not distract you from your main task. Warnings now are normal in tensorflow.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the reason of the warning? How should the code be changed to
>   avoid such warnings?

This warning is applicable only for pre-Tensorflow 2.0. The warning is there because starting from Tensorflow 2.0, `dtype` argument should be passed when calling the initializer instance and not to the constructor.

Code snippet to reproduce the warning in pre-tensorflow2.0:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
dense = Dense(64, activation='relu')
```

Output:

```
calling VarianceScaling.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
```

It is not immediately apparent why the code snippet would cause this warning because no initializer is created. What happens is that internally Tensorflow creates the initializer when a `Dense` layer is initiated, since the default kernel initializer is `glorot_uniform`. Something like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
initializer = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/024675edc62dddab17bc439b69eb9bd71f1a1a9a/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L997
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/024675edc62dddab17bc439b69eb9bd71f1a1a9a/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1014