# Keras Tensorflow warning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Can someone help me fix the following warning?

I have looked to the backend.py but cant seem to work out what the problem is, and the solution?

> WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/temp/Desktop/python_stuff/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4149: add_dispatch_support..wrapper (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where

I also have the following warning, but saw another question on stack, didn't understand it fully so I'll add to this question if anyone knows how to fix it...

> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

I have used pip to install everything and virtual env for my development
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will quote my answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951499/depreciation-warnings-in-tensorflow-keras-official-tutorial/57952272#57952272):

> tensorflow is notorious for not being backward compatible and worse yet there are warnings like this now for a long time.
>
> See here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25996
>
> So your best bet is just ignore those warnings and, if you wish to be proactive, then contribute with a fix.

Your other queston has also been answered here and you may safely ignore such warning too, especially if you use GPU:

[Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u)